# Returning multiple objects with a JSON result

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

i am wondering if it is possible to return multiple objects with a JSON result in MVC.
At the moment i have no problem to return a single object.

```
public ActionResult AddToBasket(int quantity, int productdetailid) 
{
    // more code here
    return Json ( new { Name = p.Product.Name, Price = p.Price});
}
```

This returns a single anonymous object in my ajax call.What i wanna do is return multiple Names and Prices to fill a table in my view.

So basicly i wanna update(renew) the cookie every time the user adds a item to his basket and update the basket which is a html table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `object[]{ new {...}, new {...} }` by any chance?

Comment: Return a JSON object that contains an array of objects. I can't help you with the specific server side code, however.

Comment: what programming language is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return some enumerable if you want an array:

```
return Json ( Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new { Name = "N" + i, Price = i });
```

Comment: But what if the array is dynamic?

Answer (score 6):

Simply return an array of objects, e.g:

```
[ { Name: 'foo', Price: 123 }
, { Name: 'bar', Price: 456 }
, { Name: 'baz', Price: 789 } ]
```

Comment: This is JavaScript syntax which is correct but in C# he's asking on the server-side how does he do it which is different than your answer.

Comment: Thats correct, and the data is dynamic so i dont know how much objects i need to pass.